# tkinter not working on vs code. python version 3.9.6 (no module named tkinter.__main__;)

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, visual-studio-code

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
myLabel = Label(root, text="Hello World")
myLabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Every time I run this on VS Code it gives me this error NameError: name Tk is not define.

So I go into my console from VS code and manually put python tkinter.py (which is what I have the filename called and then it says no directory found. Still in the console on VS Code I change all directories so that I'm in the file which contains tkinter.py I run both these codes in console to see what's the issue (python tkinter.py and python3 tkinter.py and same error happens) Tk is not defined

lastly I tried to run this in my VS Code console python3 -m tkinter and it worked the GUI window popped up so I know I have it installed. it just isn't working when I try and run it in from the file (tkinter.py)

Comment: If you named your own script `tkinter.py`, then the `from tkinter import *` line is trying to import *the script itself*.  Choose a non-conflicting name for your script, and get rid of any files like `tkinter.pyc` that were created in the same folder.

Comment: Certain your install affected `which python3` or a different installation?

Comment: _"I'm in the file which contains tkinter.py"_ - this is the problem. When you do `from tkinter import *` it's importing your file, not the tkinter module.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your file. Sometimes you import the file you're coding in.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32018568)